# material-table add multiselect to lookup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am using Material-Table to easily manage my data. It is fantastic, but for one feature. With the below code I get a select menu. I would like to have a multiselect menu, so i can save more then one id, ideally an array.

## Current Select

[image]

## Implementation

```
columns = [
  {
    title: 'Game Systems',
    field: 'gameSystemIds',
    type: 'numeric',
    lookup: {1: "40k", 2: "Fantasy"},
  },
]

<Table
   columns={columns}
   data={allManufacturers}
</>
```

Is it possible to use a multi select box?

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately your solution at github (https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1492#issuecomment-570833161) doesn't work for the latest version. It throws `TypeError: renderInput is not a function` for the materialUI Autocomplete component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply override the `editComponent` prop of the columns to render your custom view ( here a multi select) and update the data yourself.

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-darkness-qw16o) on how you could do it.